# Fix PaintBox Panel

Tags: c#

I'm making a paintbox, it works fine i use a panel inside a form , when i clicked on new menu it shows panel box perfectly , but on same case i also use a text box same overlap at panel when i clicked on text editor button it will no show the editor in middle where panel also place, but when i place text box at right side it will show text box, same problem with picture box. Here is the code of panel, text box editor or picture box:
For panel:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

For text box editor:

```
private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox1.Multiline = true;
}
```

Picture box:

```
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        string Chosen_File = "";
        Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Insert an image";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|GIF Images|*.gif|All Files|";
        //openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);

        }
```

but it will only show panel on middle, when i used design and place text editor and picture box in middle it will no show on run time, what is the error

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question please? At the moment it is not clear what / where the problem is and what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: i'm asking that i want to be showing same position of text box editor or picture box as the panel position at run time , but it will not show picture box or text editor when i press the button

Comment: The panel probably overlaps the textbox.  You'll have to use BringToFront() or make the panel the Parent of the textbox.